# Error reading table into R

Tags: r, read.csv

I am trying to read this [file](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/eureconometrics-assets/Dataset%20Files%20for%20On-Demand%20Course/Exercises%20and%20datasets/Module%203/TrainExer%203-1-corrected.txt) into an R dataframe but keep getting errors.

This is the command I am using

```
data <- read.csv("TrainExer 3-1-corrected.txt", sep='\t', colClasses = "numeric")
```

I get the following error

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec
>   = dec,  :    scan() expected 'a real', got '1229.2316.200'

If I don't specify `colClasses`, I don't get any error, but the table merges some entries from different columns. For example, 1229.23 is one entry in one column and 16.200 is another entry in the adjacent column. Somehow R is trying to read them as one.

Comment: Your column is not numeric, you can read your file and then use as.numeric(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should be using `read.table` instead, since you're not loading in a csv. This might work: `data <- read.table("TrainExer 3-1-corrected.txt", header = TRUE)`